# What is the purpose of upgrading your Jumpship?

Tags: destiny

Is there any point to upgrading/changing your jumpship in Destiny?

I only have the initial ship at the moment, however I have seen other players during loading screens with other ships of different styles.

Is there any statistical/tactical advantage to this or is this purely cosmetic?

Comment: It is indeed. Is the correct etiquette to delete this question now?

Comment: Click the flag button ^